# Java | What does synthetic mean?

Tags: java, class, methods, synthetic

I was going through the java `Method.class` (Decompiled) and I found something that caught my eye.

```
@Override
public boolean isSynthetic() {
    return super.isSynthetic();
}
```

"***Synthetic***". What does that mean?

Is it usable in code?

.

And since I found this in the `Method` class, I was wondering, is it that an *entire method* could be "synthetic", or is it that it *contains* something synthetic?

Thanks in advance.

.

not a copy of [What is the meaning of “static synthetic”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223268/what-is-the-meaning-of-static-synthetic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any constructs introduced by the compiler that do not have a
>   corresponding construct in the source code must be marked as
>   synthetic, except for default constructors and the class
>   initialization method.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073578/java-s-synthetic-methods.html