# As in my class no inner classes are there Java $ simple in class files

Tags: java

I have compiles one java file, suppose test.java using javac test.java

after compilation,it generates two class files test.class and test$.class.

any one help  me about that $ class files.The code is working fine.I need to understand $ class files.

is it a temp file ?

below is my code
package test.myfolder;

public class test{

```
public String Login;
public String Name;
public String Num;
public String AccNum;

public test()
{
    this.Login = Abc.getMissChar();
    this.Name = Abc.getMissChar();
    this.Num = Abc.getMissChar();
    this.AccNum = Abc.getMissChar();
}

public test(String pLogin, String pName, String pNum, String pAccNum)
{
    this.Login = pLogin;
    this.Name = pName;
    this.Num = pNum;
    this.AccNum = pNum;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return Login;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public String getNum() {
    return Num;
}

public String getAccNum() {
    return AccNum;
}
```

Comment: This is due to anonymous-inner class.

Comment: The $classfile indicated that you have used inner classes in your code. stackoverflow.com/questions/380406/java-inner-class-class-file-names may give you some idea

Comment: The $classfile indicated that you have used inner classes in your code. stackoverflow.com/questions/380406/java-inner-class-class-file-names may give you some idea

Comment: Read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399546/synthetic-class-in-java

Comment: Read this post in StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399546/synthetic-class-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If you have anonymous classes (or [maybe just a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402331/14955)), Java creates these extra class files with the `$` in them.

Those are not temporary files. Java will need them to load your class.

Comment: is there is any issue with this $ class files.I have tried to delete that one,but it shows file not found.

Comment: Don't delete it. It is not a temporary file. Java will need that file to load your class.

Comment: But in my code no inner classes are there.It is used only for set and get method for values only..I am bit confused about this $class files....

Comment: I have added the my java code also.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler really creates that file? Can you delete it and compile again?

Answer (score 1):

If a source file has more than one class, each class is compiled into a separate class file and I think there is another inner or anonymous  classes inside your class.

Comment: test.java file is an existing file.I have updated that file and compiled.In the previous case only test.class file is there.After updating the java file and compiled again with target 1.5 command(As our javac version upgraded to 1.6,I need in 1.5 ).it generates test.class and test$1.class....