# Duplicate class name in a jar and decompiler error

Tags: java, jar, decompiler

I have java class with name MyClass and inside I am adding new Object. When look at the the jar by winzip I saw the duplicated class as below.

```
MyClass$1.class
MyClass$2.class
```

and so on.

What does it mean? Is it a problem as when I tried to open that jar file with decompiler it gives the error below

> An unhandled exception occured. Press "Abort" to terminate the
>   program, "Retry" to exit the program normally and "Ignore" to try to
>   continue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `foo$something` is a [synthetic class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399546/synthetic-class-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

The original version of Java didn't have nested classes. When they were added, they were implemented as syntactic sugar in the compiler, with the classes compiled to seperate classfiles under the hood. The names use $. So MyClass$1 is an anonymous class that is contained within MyClass.

As for why your decompiler crashed, it is probably a bad decompiler. There's a lot of modern decompiles out there you can use. You could also try a tool like [BytecodeViewer](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer) or [Helios](https://github.com/helios-decompiler/Helios), which bundle together a number of different decompilers with a convenient GUI.